# Need to get the list of files created today in the unix ftp server using vbscript

Tags: unix, vbscript, ftp

Requirement is to get the list of file names created/modified today in the unix ftp server in a particular folder using vbscript.  Will that be possible?  I am very new to VBScript.  Please help me. I cant use any external softwares ,etc.

```
Set objFSO1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objwrc = objFSO1.CreateTextFile("c:\Jobs.txt", True) 
objwrc.WriteLine "open ipadress"
objwrc.WriteLine "username"
objwrc.WriteLine "password"
objwrc.WriteLine "cd foldername"
objwrc.WriteLine "dir . print.txt"
objwrc.WriteLine "quit"
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "%comspec% /c c:\windows\system32\ftp.exe -s:c:\Jobs.txt ",,true
Msgbox("Done")
```

Comment: We're not going to write your code for you. Please share what you have found and tried and show where exactly you are stuck. If you don't have anything, start by typing "vbscript ftp list directory" in your favorite web search engine. That being said: VBScript doesn't really sound like the correct solution to this problem.

Comment: Hi, I have this code written, but it is giving me the list of files in the folder.  But I need the files which are created today.
Set objFSO1 = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objwrc = objFSO1.CreateTextFile("c:\Jobs.txt", True) 
objwrc.WriteLine "open ipadress"
objwrc.WriteLine "username"
objwrc.WriteLine "password"
objwrc.WriteLine "cd foldername"
objwrc.WriteLine "dir . print.txt"
objwrc.WriteLine "quit"
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.Run "%comspec% /c c:\windows\system32\ftp.exe -s:c:\Jobs.txt ",,true
Msgbox("Done")

Comment: Then please share the code you currently have by editing your question .

Answer (score 0):

I would create a script like this, called `ftp.script`:

```
open a.b.c.d
user username password
dir
quit
```

where a.b.c.d is the IP address or name of your FTP server.

Then you will need to execute a process that does this:

```
ftp -n -s:ftp.script
```

and parse the output.

If you want to parse the output, you could do something like this:

```
output=split(createobject("wscript.Shell").exec("cmd /c DIR ").stdout.readall,vbCrLf)
for i=0 to ubound(output)
     msgbox output(i)
next
```

but change the command to execute your FTP script.

You may need to be careful of the definition of "today" because the server may be in a different timezone to you...